# Какой триггер сработает первее

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица Table1, на ней висит триггер на удаление(for delete) T_Table1
Есть таблица Table2, на ней висит тоже висит триггер на удаление T_Table2
В таблице Table2 есть ссылка на ключ Table1, правило удаления каскадно.

Вопрос: когда удаляется запись из таблицы Table1, на которую ссылается запись из Table2, какой триггер сработает первее?  Опытным путем установлено что второй, но всегда ли такое поведение одинаково?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Все каскадные ссылочные действия,
> прямо вызванные исходными инструкциями
> DELETE или UPDATE, выполняются
> первыми.

`http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx`, раздел "Триггеры и каскадные ссылочные действия"